# When I try to save my wire frame project and i open it the next time some of the meshes vertices disappear

Tags: animation

I replicated a plane and made different vertices. I saved it and opened it again but some of the  the mesh lines disappeared. By the way I used mirror modifier to replicate one side of the plane.

Comment: Is it possible you could add some screenshots and/or a .blend demonstrating this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider taking the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and checking out sections of the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help). One thing you may not be aware of, is that in object mode, some of the vertices and edges of an object which are visible in edit mode, do not usually display in object mode. If the vertices or edge lines have disappeared, check to make sure you are in edit mode.